# WebRTC Errors recording video

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video, video-recording

I've tested https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/, however it doesn't appear to function on iPhone, in Safari or Chrome, presenting getUserMedia errors.

The errors occur by default, I haven't changed settings, never tried this before, and it never prompts for camera access.

Clicking Start Camera:

iPhone Safari: navigator.getUserMedia error:Error: Invalid constraint

iPhone Chrome: navigator.getUserMedia error:TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sais the constraint is invalid.
This is the constraint they are using:

```
const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: {exact: hasEchoCancellation}
    },
    video: {
      width: 1280, height: 720
    }
  };
```

could be echoCancellation is not supported on the safari. So maybe change the code to just

```
{
  audio: true, 
  video: {
    width: 1280, height: 720
  }
}
```